# Why the output of my node code in gitbash has several line spaces

Tags: node.js

I do not know why is this happening, I have reinstalled node and git, but the problem remains,

This is my simple node code

console.log("All is done!");

and the output looks like this,
https://pasteboard.co/IcuxPrj.jpg

The console output has several empty lines after it

Comment: You can find the reason here : https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout, read the warning section.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with empty lines after node command. But the solution was expand the git bash terminal window a bit vertically